# How to replace part of string to something else using awk?

Tags: awk, replace

I  have  a file that looks like this with 12 columns and ~7000000 rows

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  T_STAT  P
23  154918459   X:154918459:C:G C   G   G   ADD 1460    0.067883    0.039459    1.72034 0.0855842
1   54712   1:54712 TTTTC   T   ADD 1460    0.00428077  0.0561095   0.0762931   0.939196
1   825069  rs4475692   G   C   G   ADD 1460    -0.000411661    0.0413083   -0.00996558 0.99205
1   825410  rs13303179  G   A   G   ADD 1460    0.00489633  0.041967    0.116671    0.907137
23  154927183   X:154927183:C:T C   T   T   ADD 1460    0.0717408   0.080978    0.885931    0.375803
```

Column three has different formats e.g. rs509981:154925045:C:T, X:154927183:C:T or 23:57937183:C:T

I only want to change the occurrence of **X:** into **23:** Therefore, for my example, the output should look like this:

I tried the command below but it didn't work. I suspect because the command is finding occurrences of X: as a whole character rather than as part of a string. Btw I am not sure whether string is the correct word.

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  T_STAT  P
23  154918459   23:154918459:C:G    C   G   G   ADD 1460    0.067883    0.039459    1.72034 0.0855842
1   54712   1:54712 TTTTC   T   ADD 1460    0.00428077  0.0561095   0.0762931   0.939196
1   825069  rs4475692   G   C   G   ADD 1460    -0.000411661    0.0413083   -0.00996558 0.99205
1   825410  rs13303179  G   A   G   ADD 1460    0.00489633  0.041967    0.116671    0.907137
23  154927183   23:154927183:C:T    C   T   T   ADD 1460    0.0717408   0.080978    0.885931    0.375803
```

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $3=="X:" {sub(/^X/,"23:")}1' file.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: `awk 'NR>1{sub(/^X:/,"23:",$3)}1'`. In general, you can use `~` instead of `==` to do a regexp match.

Comment: The above from @jhnc will work, but it will change the formatting a bit. Assuming you have a tab-delimited file, you might want to do something like  `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` before that above line. If the file is not tab-delimeted but with actual multiple spaces, it might be in your case best to do something like: `{t=$3;sub(/^X:/,"23:",t);sub($3,t)}1`

Comment: @kvantour That looks like a good suggestion, why not post it? :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I just wanted to quickly help somebody out. I don't think this is worth writing as an answer as there are many equivalent questions around.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '1!s/\([^ ]* \)\{2\}X\(.*\)/\123\2/' input_file
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  T_STAT  P
23  154918459  23:154918459:C:G C   G   G   ADD 1460    0.067883    0.039459    1.72034 0.0855842
1   54712   1:54712 TTTTC   T   ADD 1460    0.00428077  0.0561095   0.0762931   0.939196
1   825069  rs4475692   G   C   G   ADD 1460    -0.000411661    0.0413083   -0.00996558 0.99205
1   825410  rs13303179  G   A   G   ADD 1460    0.00489633  0.041967    0.116671    0.907137
23  154927183  23:154927183:C:T C   T   T   ADD 1460    0.0717408   0.080978    0.885931    0.375803
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
awk '{sub("X:","23:",$3)}1' input.txt
```

#### Explanation for `awk` script:

`{sub("X:","23:",$3)}` In each line, in 3rd field, Replace first occurrence of `X:` with `23:`

`1` Print each line, changed or not.